# C# linq sorts number in a wrong sequence

Tags: c#, list, linq, sorting, point

I just had the problem with C# linq sorting with number. I sorted the list which includes 4 points and each point has the value of X,Y and Z. Most of the time, the sorting works like a charmm, but sometimes it made the wrong sequence as the picture below and I can't not figure it out why. I would be appreciated your help.

```
List<Point> listsorted = listpoint.OrderBy(x => x.Z).ThenBy(x => x.X).ThenBy(x => x.Y).ToList();
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GC242.png)

Comment: Most likely the floating point numbers have more digits than is visible, and thus they dictate the order, for instance, the ones with seemingly equal X might not be equal, they just look that way.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Yes you are right. Problem was solved. Thank you for your explaination. I forgot it is a floating type so after using Math.Round I got the correct sorting order already.

Comment: Well, just interesting, why do you use .ToList() ? Are you going to work with it as List ? Ie CRUD operations ?